# Paraview glyphs too packed issues

Tags: paraview, glyph

I was visualizing my vorticity vector field and notice that I am not able to see the pattern without zooming in as there are too many glyphs and are too packed.

Currently, I am using a calculator to combine X,Y,Z vorticity field into a single vector field using the calculator. Take a slice of it and do a glyph filter visualizing all points on the plane.

I notice that one possible way is to visualize a curved glyphs and scale up a little bit to make it more noticeable, but not sure how to do that. Does anyone know whats the steps to do that? Or any other suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reducing the **Maximum Number of Sample Points** property in the **Properties Panel** when the **Glyph** filter is selected in the **Pipeline Browser**? You may also want to change the **Scale Factor** property to change the length of the glyphs.

Comment: Is the scale factor changing the size of the glyphs instead of the length? I think I tried the scale factor before, and turns out it seems like changing the size of the glyphs @Cory Quammen

Comment: Yes, it uniformly scales the glyphs, not just shrinking it in length. You can adjust the **Tip Radius** and **Shaft Radius** independently from the **Scale Factor** to effectively change the length of the glyphs.